# Select Records based on Count of Child Records Matching Specified Criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have two Tables in an SQL 08 database:

- Clients
- Balances

  - ClientID (foreign key to clients)
  - isStartingBalance (bit)

Using SQL, I need to locate and update all Balance Records where the Client the Balance Record belongs to has only one balance record, and that balance record has isStartingBalance=0. I need to update those records so that isStartingBalance=1.

How might I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find clients with only one balance row:

```
update  Balances
set     isStartingBalance = 1
where   isStartingBalance = 0
        and ClientID in
        (
        select  ClientID
        from    Balances
        group by
                ClientID
        having  count(*) = 1
        )
```

Or more sensibly, you can update the oldest balance row for each customer:

```
update  bal
set     isStartingBalance = 1
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by ClientID 
                    order by dt) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Balance
        ) bal
where   rn = 1
        and isStartingBalance = 0
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2111c/1/0)

An even more sensible solution would be to remove the `isStartingBalance` column entirely, and query for it when you need it:

```
select  ClientID
,       dt
,       case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end as isStartingBalance
from    (
        select  ClientID
        ,       dt
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by ClientID
                    order by dt) as rn
        from    Balance
        ) SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar. I think your first example will work for my case.